# Intel Network Connection: This device cannot start. (Code 10)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, network-adapter, device-manager

I have a Intel® Desktop Board DP55KG (see http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/motherboards/DP55KG/DP55KG-overview.htm), which has a Intel 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection on board. Additionally, I have a Intel PRO/1000 PT Dual Port Server Adapter in a PCI express slot and I am running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit. Also I am running with Intels latest network driver, in the 82578DC questions this means 11.6.92.0 with driver date 2010.04.12.

The problem I am having is that the Intel 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection will not start on boot with the following message: "This device cannot start. (Code 10)". Disabling and then enabling the device after boot makes the network connection work again without any problems, but as soon as I reboot the problem occurs again.

Any suggestion how to fix this? I have seen this problem on another Intel S3420GP board as well in Windows 7 that is.

Answer (score 1):

Update the BIOS.

1. Download the update [from the Intel site](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19289&ProdId=3125)
2. Execute the file, it will update your BIOS automatically.
3. Don't power down!
4. Wait and all should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the DH55TC and Windows 7 x64. No amount of adding or removing the driver helped, or hard or soft rebooting. However, I did try reinstalling the latest Intel driver and unselecting all additional options like the property pages and teaming/VLAN support. With just Drivers checked during the install, the adapter worked.