# "This device cannot start" error - Intel motherboard, 3-COM NIC

Tags: networking, motherboard, network-adapter

I have an old(ish) computer with an Intel D850EMV2 board. I've installed a 3COM 3C-905C-TX NIC on it. Windows boots fine, but the NIC exhibits a

```
This device cannot start (Code 10)
```

error. My BIOS is the latest version (P25), so the solution [suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/142375/intel-network-connection-this-device-cannot-start-code-10) won't work.

Why does this happen? What can I do to resolve it, other than replace the NIC?

The NIC is known to be functioning properly (tested on another computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to run into this around the time that board was introduced (I used to work for an Intel Premier Provider), so I think I know what's going on here...

That motherboard has partially-implemented SMBus routing, in that it's only applied to one (or maybe two) of the PCI slots.

My *guess* would be you have the NIC in the last (5th) PCI slot (PCI slot #4, the PCI are slots 0-4, with 0 being closest to he AGP slot).  The last PCI slot has SMBus enabled, but the card uses the SMBus pins for something else, confusing the motherboard/BIOS.

Try putting it in another PCI slot (I recommend using the 3rd PCI slot).

Reference document from Intel: [Intel® Desktop Board D850EMV2 Specification Update](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15336/eng/D850EMV2_SpecUpdate08.pdf)
Specifically see page 13, section 5 "Clarification of SMBus Routing".

Comment: Actually I had it in slot 2, but moving it to slot 1 did the trick for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason is drivers. Ensure you have the proper driver installed: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/0a7e3177-4b7d-4da2-979c-f13e0eb33f7d/

Comment: Drivers were up-to-date.